# Can GQLAlchemy be used to validate the scheme of the dataset?

Tags: memgraphdb

Memgraph is schemaless, but some use cases require strict validation rules. Instead of enforcing the schema in Memgraph is there a way to enforce it easily in GQLAlchemy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can enforce it.  Memgraph uses [Pydantic](https://docs.pydantic.dev/). It's actually very Pythonic. Please take a look at [tests/ogm/test_loading.py](https://github.com/memgraph/gqlalchemy/blob/main/tests/ogm/test_loading.py) in the GitHub repo to see the code.